# Insert select using default values

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-insert

I am trying to copy one table to another and if one of the items from the original table is null insert a default value instead.

```
INSERT INTO Table2(ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT Table1.ColA, Table1.ColB, (if Table1.ColC is null {'NewValue'} else {Table1.ColC})
```

No idea if I am anywhere close to a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT ColA, ColB, ISNULL(ColC, 'newvalue')
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT ColA, 
       ColB, 
       case when ColC is null 
            then 'NewValue' 
            else ColC
       end
from Table1
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT ColA, 
       ColB, 
       coalesce(ColC, 'newValue')
from Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to create a DEFAULT constraint on the table. Then, anytime you try to insert NULL you get the DEFAULT value instead:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table2_ColC DEFAULT 'newValue' FOR ColC
```